# Glue operator ignores "iam_role_name" parameter

Tags: airflow, aws-glue, mwaa

I am trying to have a DAG trigger a Glue job. I have a role that can run these Glue jobs, and I want the Glue task to assume this role. The operator has a parameter called [`iam_role_name`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/2.4.0/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue/index.html), but when I pass the name of my Glue role as this parameter, it still tries to execute as the Airflow role rather than assuming the role I gave.

I contacted AWS support and they said that basically my options are:

- Create a connection tied to the Glue role, and use that connection for the operator
- Add the Glue permissions to the Airflow role
- Use their own operator: https://github.com/aws-samples/mwaa-rbac-task

It seems to me that the developers of `AwsGlueJobHook` intended the `iam_role_name` parameter to be the easy way to assume roles. Yet the parameter seems to have no effect in practice. Why is this?

---

I am using:

- Airflow 2.2.2 via AWS MWAA
- apache-airflow-providers-amazon 2.4.0

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz Unfortunately nothing beyond what I said in the question. Creating a connection works, adding the policy to the MWAA execution role also works. That's about all I've found.

Answer (score 0):

In [AwsGlueJobHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5a113f302769f0ecad3a54bad3027d459cb276a4/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue.py#L26), the `iam_role_name` is used in [this method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5a113f302769f0ecad3a54bad3027d459cb276a4/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue.py#L91) to get the role information, and from these information, it uses only the [role arn](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5a113f302769f0ecad3a54bad3027d459cb276a4/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue.py#L186) as an argument for the method `create_job` which create you job.

But in fact, the role/user used to create the client is the one found in the airflow connection.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Could you try rephrasing a bit?